# The DateDiff function for MS Access on pyodbc is giving me a 'too few parameters error'

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

My query is pretty simple:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT DATEDIFF(n, InTime, OutTime) AS New FROM AttendanceLogs')
```

I have tried everything from typing it as minute instead of n, typing n with single quotes, verifying the columns in the table, typing \60 before AS and various other methods suggested on the internet. I am yet to find an answer. I keep getting an message which reads:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it should really be like this: `'SELECT DATEDIFF("d", InTime, OutTime) AS New FROM AttendanceLogs')`, notice the double quote in the first variable in `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Another option: you can just calculate `[OutTime] - [InTime]` to get the difference

Comment: Double quotes did nothing for me. Same error. Directly trying to subtract it resulted in ```pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLGetData)')```. The dates seem to be in string format.

Comment: Aha.... you need to cast the string variable into date format. let me know if you need help with that

Comment: Thank you, MEdwin. I can take it from here. Appreciate you helping out.